# Throws the output ########### in sql developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

when i execute the below script it doesnt print the value. Kinldy help me to solve as soon as possible

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
v_upd_value         VARCHAR2(50);
v_dscnt_pcnt        NUMBER := '22222222.22';
begin
v_upd_value := trim(to_char(v_dscnt_pcnt,'9999990.99'));
dbms_output.put_line('update value :'||v_upd_value);
```

end;

thanks in advance

Comment: It could be the result of a narrowing conversion.  What happens when you add a 9 here, v_upd_value := trim(to_char(v_dscnt_pcnt,'99999990.99')); ?

Comment: Hi Smith, it will work fine and thanks for your comments

Comment: but my intention is to print the value given as such with the given number or digits

Comment: So you're saying it appears correctly, but you're wanting to drop the scale?  v_dscnt_pcnt        NUMBER(10,2) := '22222222.2'; or '2222222.22'; ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more 9 in to_char function as below.

```
declare
  v_upd_value         VARCHAR2(50);
  v_dscnt_pcnt        NUMBER := '22222222.22';
begin
  v_upd_value := trim(to_char(v_dscnt_pcnt,'99999990.99'));
  dbms_output.put_line('update value :'||v_upd_value);
end;
```

Hope this helps..